# Twitter API code to find specific cities

Tags: python-2.7, api, twitter

So far I have this code:

```
with open("real estate data.csv", "a") as myfile:
      myfile.write('"{0}",'.format((tweets.user.location).encode('utf8')))
```

Which can find me the location of users on the `Twitter API` when they make a Tweet.

However, it returns broad locations such as New York, but what if I wanted to find specific cities or areas, like `Times Square, New York` instead of all of New York.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latitude and longitude coordinates are specified under the `coordinates` field, however those coordinates are only specified in case the user **explicitly** shared their location while tweeting.

To access it simply use `tweet.coordinates`, here is an example:

```
"coordinates":[-97.51087576,35.46500176]
```

Read more about coordinates in the [`doc`](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/tweets#obj-coordinates).

This used to be part of the `geo` field which is [deprecated](http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-development-talk/browse_thread/thread/9e4ea75178174908) now so it will always be equal to null.

Read more about how geolocation works within the Twitter API [here](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/terms/geo-developer-guidelines).

Comment: thank you for your comment! I will try that out and let you know!